# How to create table where url is unique depending on id?

Tags: postgresql

I have created two tables using PostgreSQL by using this command:

```sql
CREATE TABLE stores (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name TEXT
);


CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL, 
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    image TEXT,
    url TEXT UNIQUE, 
    added_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, store_id)
);


ALTER TABLE products
ADD  CONSTRAINT "FK_products_stores" FOREIGN KEY ("store_id")
        REFERENCES stores (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

and what I want to achieve is that whenever I try to insert a url e.g.

```
store_id=1 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
store_id=2 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
```

That should not return that there is a duplicate key value meaning that I want to have a sort check to see whenever a URL exists in specific store_id, if two urls are the same with same store_id then I should get the duplicate key error but otherwise if the store_id are unique and url are the same then it should not appear any duplicate error.

My question is if that is possible by using postgresql or does this need to be handled in other ways?

EDIT:

And of course whenever we have two identical e.g

```
store_id=1 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
store_id=1 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
```

then it should return error key duplicated

—————————————————————

Expect:

```
store_id=1 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
store_id=2 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com

No duplicate key error
```

Actual:

```
store_id=1 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com
store_id=2 and url=http://pythonisthebest.com

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_url_key"
```

Comment: don't add the UNIQUE constraint to url, instead make url part of the primary key

Comment: You need a table constraint. `unique(store_id, url)`

Comment: @Portal but then what happens if I have two same url in the same store id? then I would have a duplicated?

Comment: @klin How do I do that if my table is already created? Can I alter it, if yes, how would I be able to do that?

Comment: @PythonNewbie two entries are only considered to be duplicates if the entire primary key is the same for both. so if the primary key is the composite of store_id and url then yes both store_id and url would have to be the same for a duplicate error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table constraint. You can alter the existing table with

```sql
alter table products 
    drop constraint products_url_key,
    add unique(store_id, url);
```

Comment: So that means I dont really nedd the products_url_key even in first place?

Comment: You can't keep the unique column constraint, you have to replace it with a two-column one.